# Making my module HMR ready

Tags: javascript, webpack, redux

Working on a big project with a ReactJS + Redux + Webpack setup.

The HMR functionality saves me a lot of time both with components and containers. However, sometimes I get this warning:

[image: warning]

When I followed the [link to Webpack docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html#from-the-module-view) it says:

> In general, the module developer writes handlers that are called when a dependency of this module is updated. They can also write a handler that is called when this module is updated.

But I couldn't find any instructions on how to do so.

My module that is causing the warning for reference:

```
import  { ear, jobs } from '../../constants/Voice';

export const respondToWord = (wordInfo, selectedElement) => {

    switch (wordInfo.key) {
        case ear.NEXT.key:
            return {type: 'NEXT_TAG'};

        case ear.NUMBER.key:
            return {type: 'SET_BACKGROUND_IMAGE', value: wordInfo.word};

        case ear.VALUE.key:
            return {type: 'SET_BACKGROUND_IMAGE', value: wordInfo.word};

    }
}
```